# Simulating data for linear regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, simulation, iid

I am trying to simulate two data set for multiple linear regression. I want one data which is independent and identically distributed and the other is not. So far, I have done the following:

```
x1 <- rnorm(10000,11,.5)
x2<-rnorm(10000,5,95)
x3 <- rnorm(10000,5,.5)


b1 <- 0.1
b2 <- 0.9
b3 <- 0.6
sigma <- 0.4

eps <- rnorm(x1,10000,sigma)
y <- b1*x1  + b2*x2  + b3*x3  +eps
Y<-as.matrix(y)
X<-cbind(as.matrix(x1),as.matrix(x2),as.matrix(x3))
```

Does this satisfy the iid case? How to generate data that is **not** iid? For non iid case I am thinking of having autocorrelation.

Comment: check my edited answer for more related discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this satisfy the iid case?

Yes.

> How to generate data that is not iid?

For example, data is generated from a mixture of Gaussian. When generate samples, we first sample the "membership", the according to the membership, we sample different Gaussian distribution.

**In addition, Note that, linear regression does not have the assumption on the distribution on $X$, only on the residual to be normal distribution ed with constant variance, because of [Gauss–Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem).**

In other words, your simulation satisfy linear regression assumptions and the simulation has stronger assumptions on distribution of $X$.

---

In your comment, you asked how to generate not IID on residuals, I think you have a confusion on the assumptions. IID is on data, and normal distribution is on residuals.

---

Related topics

[Regression when the OLS residuals are not normally distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/regression-when-the-ols-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed)

[Why is the normality of residuals "barely important at all" for the purpose of estimating the regression line?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152674/why-is-the-normality-of-residuals-barely-important-at-all-for-the-purpose-of-e)

[Assumptions of multiple regression: how is normality assumption different from constant variance assumption?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276831/assumptions-of-multiple-regression-how-is-normality-assumption-different-from-c)

[What is a complete list of the usual assumptions for linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/what-is-a-complete-list-of-the-usual-assumptions-for-linear-regression)

[How does linear regression use the normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148803/how-does-linear-regression-use-the-normal-distribution)

Comment: How can I generate the data which violates this assumption on residuals?

Comment: I was referring to your comment "In other words, your simulation satisfy linear regression assumptions and the simulation has stronger assumptions on distribution of X". I just wanted residual not normal, I did not use the word iid and residuals. Apologies for creating confusion

Answer (score 1):

To generate correlated independent variables, you could do something like this:

```
x1 <- rnorm(10^5,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(10^5,0,1)
x2 <- 0.4*x1 + sqrt(1-0.4^2)*x2
x1 <- 11 + 0.5*x1
x2 <- 5 + 95*x2
```

There are ways to do something comparable with 3 or more variables, as well...though I will stop here for now.

For autocorrelation, a similar strategy can be used:

```
sigma <- 0.4
eps <- rnorm(10^5,0,1)
for(i in 2:10^5) eps[i] <- 0.15 * eps[i-1] + sqrt(1-0.15^2)*eps[i]
eps <- sigma * eps
```

Hope this helps with your simulation.

Comment: The 2nd chunk produces an error.

Comment: Should be updated now.