# Why do ridges in parameter space make things hard to estimate?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, likelihood, geometry

In this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279111/151862 Glen_b says

> The reason is that the d.f. parameter [of a t distribution] is very hard to estimate well
>   from data, particularly if you're also estimating the scale parameter.
>   Indeed you can often end up with either silly estimates or unstable
>   estimates (e.g. from a ridge in parameter space)

I'm assuming he is talking about the geometry of the likelihood as a function of the parameters. Can someone explain why exactly a ridge makes things harder to estimate?

Comment: Have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7308?  That concerns precisely this circumstance.  The answers illustrate the geometry and connect it with the optimization procedure.

Comment: Thanks! Basically, the optimizer gets inside the ridge, can't climb out and thinks it's the minimum right?

Comment: That's about right.  In the case I referenced, there is no "out" to climb towards: it's an infinite valley with infinitely high sides.  Think of a real valley whose slope eventually becomes essentially flat: its river stops flowing appreciably and just disappears into a meandering swamp.  Numerical searches for minima suffer the same fate: they meander slowly, without being able to tell where "downhill" is, and may never be able to determine the lowest point (which could be miles away within the swamp). A good optimizer will tell you that's what happened (usually in a return code).

Comment: But in that case, if the likelihood is so flat wrt to the parameters, does it really matter? Pick anything from the swamp and the result is roughly the same.

Comment: One major point of the thread I linked to is the results can be entirely different!  Even qualitatively the two fits found by `R` and *Mathematica* are obviously different. In statistics, one major purpose of optimization is to estimate parameters: one is not directly interested in what the particular value of the objective function might be.  (It does play a role in assessing the uncertainty of the estimates.)

Comment: NB: A "ridge" is an upside-down valley.  Just as the optimizer may have trouble navigating the valley because it appears flat everywhere, it will have trouble navigating a ridge and can conclude that points on the ridge are *minima,* even though they are nearly local *maxima.*  Thus, settling for almost good enough--in response to your "does it really matter question"--could be a profound mistake.