# Regression models with uncertainty as T-Distribution

Tags: error, measurement-error, marginal-distribution

Are there any distributions which represent uncertainty about $\hat y$ as a $t$ distribution.
In other words: $ p(y\mid x, ~\text{model}) \sim \mathbf T(\hat y, \text{df}, \sigma)$ where $\bf T$ is a non standard t distribution.

I suppose this could just be done by assigning the assumption to a simple regression. But does it ever come up naturally in any probability distributions?

Comment: Look into link functions as used in generalized linear models, e.g., https://www.statisticshowto.com/link-function/

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120776/why-should-we-use-t-errors-instead-of-normal-errors   answer your question?